# Laravel - how to list all keys on relation in collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, frameworks

I have something like:

```
$categories = Categories::with('sections')->get();
```

It gives me that collection:

[image: img]

As you can see on image I can access all "Y"'es by

```
dd($categories->pluck('id'));
```

Which gives me what I wanted, all ID's of items in this collection

[image]

But question is

How now get all ID's of "Y" ? which are attributes of relationship that belongs to each of these items

And I don't want to do that by foreaching. <---- I know how to do it that way.

But There must be better way, faster.

How to achieve it without needless foreaching this collection over and over :)?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships

Comment: @ThomasMoors I have read all of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply retrieve all the ids in sections using dot notations using the example below:

You have:

```
$categories = Categories::with('sections')->get();
```

Getting the ids of all sections will be:

```
$sections = $categories->pluck('sections.*.id')->flatten()->values();
```

This will access the collections based on depth, `sections-all-ids`. and return a reindexed underlying array.

The same if you just need the sections, you can stop at sections.

> PS: Just as @Jerodev mentioned, collections only wraps the php array in more useful ways, and the underlying pluck and many of these operations use loops.

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly you want all section ids for the categories in that collection?

You can use a second query for this using `whereIn` with the ids of these categories. Also, the `with` function is no longer needed.

```
$categories = Categories::get();
$sections = Section::whereIn('category_id', $categories->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Comment: Can't it be done with doing Categories::with('sections') + without foreaching?

Comment: You could use collections to merge the relations of the categories, but internally, that still uses foreach loops. So no, I don't think there is a another way. Keep in mind that my answer does not do more queries than the way you would like it to work because I removed the `with`.